I have had this same infestation for 2 years on my fig tree. It does appear to be a spidery webb like a maggot under the web
I have had the same infestation for the last 2 years. When you wet the web and pull it off the leaf there is always what looks like a maggot under the web. Does anyone know what it is?

A picture would help a lot!

I have seen something similar before, I just can't think of the name right now. If you have a week or two before harvest, apply some neem oil thoroughly to the undersides of the leaf late in the evening when temperatures cool down. Neem oil is derived from the castor plant, and shouldn't hurt anything.
